# Receive 400 "Bad request" when attempting to Post message via RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate, restful-architecture

I have this piece of code to POST a message

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Credentials Credentials = new Credentials();

    Credentials.setDomainId ("domain");
    Credentials.setLogin        ("login");
    Credentials.setPasswd       ("pwd");

    SmsMessage smsMessage = new SmsMessage();   

    smsMessage.setAck(false);
    smsMessage.setConcat(false);
    smsMessage.setDestination("33470855146");
    smsMessage.setMsg("This is a test");

    SmsMessages smsMessages = new SmsMessages();

    List<SmsMessage> messages = new ArrayList<SmsMessage>();
    messages.add(smsMessage);

    smsMessages.setCredentials(Credentials);
    smsMessages.setMessages(messages);

    HttpEntity<SmsMessages> request = new HttpEntity<>(smsMessages);    
    URI sms = restTemplate.postForLocation(POST_MESSAGE_URL, request);
```

But I am getting a  400 "Bad request" . Is there a way to know exactly the JSon String I am sending to try the request from command line - with curl ??

Comment: Why can't you just log the request, as it's the entity containing your json body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using spring boot you can do so by enabling the debug logging by:

`logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG`

`logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG`

You can also try turning on the DEBUG level for the RestTemplate class itself

`logging.level.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate=DEBUG`

Comment: How should I do if I'm using spring 4.X not spring boot